# cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY) returns NULL

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have a piece of c++ code:

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY); //tried (0) too
    if(capture == NULL)
        std::cout<<"NULL"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and compile it using:

```
g++ main.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags` `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

and the result of `./a.out` is

```
NULL
```

I use OpenCV 2.4.2 and Ubuntu 12.04

But I am sure that my webcam is good because the following python code works fine.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow('frame', frame) # it shows a correct image from the webcam
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Does anyone have idea why I cannot read my webcam in the C++ code?

Update:

I then upgrade OpenCV to 2.4.8 and compile the C++ code again.
The output is still NULL be it shows some error message:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT

NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that it says that **"Device/Resource is busy"**...i think that you are using your webcam somewhere else...e.g. skype etc. Else try to use the following code:

Try to use (1) instead of (0)

```
VideoCapture cap(1);

for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    imshow("My webcam", frame);
}
```

The above code is for C++ format and if you want to get an IplImage you can add the following line to convert the "frame" which is in Mat format into IplImage* format

```
IplImage* img = new IplImage(frame);
cvShowImage("IplImage format webcam", img);
```

Comment: I don't know. The python code works and I think I don't have other programs running that use the webcam.

Comment: ok...but i have also received the same error and found that my webcam was busy in an another application.

Answer (score 0):

Then I rebooted the system and it is solved. Well...

Comment: i think that the problem was that your webcam was busy somewhere which i have mentioned in my answer. Please accept the answer if you agree :)

Comment: Yes maybe you are right. Thank you. But I want to know if the device is busy why can the python code work?

Answer (score 0):

Defaultly when you connect your camera to your linux system, a process called "motion" will keep it occupied.
You have to kill it. The following command will find and kill the "motion".

> sudo killall -9 motion

After executing this, I guess your code will work. Please do share if you managed to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you but I worked on it a few years ago and I am not able to reproduce it now :( Thank you very much anyway!